# Как открыть ссылку во фрейме?

Tags: html, javascript

На сайте форма отправляется через аякс.
После отправки формы нужно во фрейме открыть ссылку.

Делаю следующим образом:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mailer.php',
        data: data,
        success: function() 
`              `{
                parent.framename.location.href = "http://yandex.ru";
        }       
   });
```

framename - имя фрейма. Но ссылка во фрейме не открывается. Как можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы из одного дочернего фрейма хотите управлять другим?

Comment: Ошибку понял про parent. Работает framename.location.href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location.href = link;